# crackling sound when using Matlab's wavread()

Tags: matlab, audio, playback

When I read a wav-file:

```
y=wavread('file.wav');
```

and then play it:

```
soundsc(y,48000)
```

the sound ist crackling. When I play the file with a mediaplayer, there is no problem. The Samplingrate of 48000 is corrent.

Comment: Does the same issue occur if you use `sound` rather than `soundsc`?

Comment: yes, with sound it's the same

Comment: Are you on a Mac? http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/264104

Comment: no, I'm on Linux (CentOS 6.5)

Comment: 1) Check if the crackling remains if you write the data `y` out again with `audiowrite` or `wavwrite` and then use the media player. 2) Check if it remains if you play the sound back at the standard sampling. 3) Check crackling appears if you play `gong.mat` or other MATLAB sample audio files back at 48000.  I suspect this is an issue with MATLAB playback at higher sample rates, not the read/write functions. If so you might have to contact Mathworks.